# odoo / openERP one2many fields dynamic domain

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-8

I want to search records of one2many field that depends on another fields.
here my code,

Parent class:

```
class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    customer_product_ids = fields.One2many('product.product',
                           compute='_get_partner_products')
    order_line = fields.One2many('sale.order.line', 'order_id')
```

Child class:

```
class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order.line'

    order_id = fields.Many2one('sale.order')
    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product')
```

View

```
 <record id="view_ata_sale_order_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">view.ata.sale.order.form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="partner_id" position="after">
                <field name="partner_channel_id" invisible="1"/>
                <field name="customer_product_ids"/>
            </field>
            <xpath expr="//tree/field[@name='product_id']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="domain">[('id', 'in', [rec.id for rec in parent.customer_product_ids])]</attribute>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

By default, a customer can see all the products defined.
In my case, I need to filter the products depends on customer selected.
*Each customer can have different list products or if they didn't categorize they can see all the products*.

I tried the code above but got error:

```
Uncaught Error: Expected "]", got "(name)"
```

I guess the error come from this code:

```
<attribute name="domain">[('id', 'in', [rec.id for rec in parent.partner_product_ids])]</attribute>
```

my question,
is it possible to do python loop comprehension like the code above (within view)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In your case you need to use `onchange` and return dynamic domain to your one2many field

you should have some thing like this:

```
@api.onchange('partner')
def onchange_partner(self):
    ids=search for products that have this partner
    then return some thing like this {'domain': {'Many2one or One2many': [('id', 'in', ids)}}
```

i will not write the code for you,so you must search for the `onchange` and apply it.You can find some info [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.api.onchange) .

Comment: hello Mostafa,  yeah, I'm a new guy for odoo development, I've tried your suggestion but it's not working as the expected. I have post my solution, and it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't put such code in there. I'd do it in a different way:

Change the product model adding its customer

```
class Product(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.product'

    parent_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner')
```

then the view can be changed much easier:

```
<attribute name="domain">[('partner_id', '=', partner_id)]</attribute>
```

or

```
<attribute name="domain">[('partner_id', '=', parent.partner_id)]</attribute>
```

(depending on where is your product_id field...

Comment: Hello Alessandro, thanks for your suggestion, I think I've found another way to make it :)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the solution from Mostafa Mohamed, but it's not affected the products list (they keep displaying all the products).
[What should onchange methods do and return?](https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/how-to/developers-13/what-should-onchange-methods-do-and-return-57760)

Here my code,

```
@api.multi
def onchange_partner_id(self, part):
    res = super(SaleOrder, self).onchange_partner_id(part)
    domain = [('active', '=', True), ('sale_ok', '=', True)]
    if part:
        partner = self.env['res.partner'].browse(part)
        if partner and partner.sales_channel_id:
            domain.append(('sales_channel_ids', '=',
                           partner.sales_channel_id.id))
    product_ids = self.env['product.product'].search(domain)
    res.update(domain={
        'order_line.product_id': ['id', 'in', [rec.id for rec in product_ids]]
    })
    return res
```

I've tried another solution, so I override *search_name* and *search* method within *product.product* model and it's works.

here my code,

1. inherit sale_view.xml

   ```
   <xpath expr="//tree/field[@name='product_id']" position="attributes">
       <attribute name="domain">[
           ('sales_channel_ids', '=', parent.partner_channel_id),
           ('sale_ok', '=', True),
           ('active', '=', True)
       ]</attribute>
       <attribute name="context">{
           'partner_channel_id': parent.partner_channel_id,
           'partner_id': parent.partner_id,
           'quantity': product_uom_qty,
           'pricelist': parent.pricelist_id,
           'uom': product_uom,
           'company_id': parent.company_id
       }</attribute>
    </xpath>
   ```

and the override method
2) *search_name* method:

```
@api.model
def name_search(self, name, args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100):
    if 'partner_channel_id' in self._context:
        target_domain = findDomain(args, 'sales_channel_ids')
        if len(target_domain) == 1:
            idx = target_domain.keys()[0]
            domain = target_domain.values()[0]
            if False in domain:
                args.pop(idx)
    return super(ProductProduct, self).name_search(name=name,
                                               args=args,
                                               operator=operator,
                                               limit=limit)
```

3. *search* method:

   ```
   @api.model
   def search(self, args, offset=0, limit=None, order=None, count=False):
       if 'partner_channel_id' in self._context:
           target_domain = findDomain(args, 'sales_channel_ids')
           if len(target_domain) == 1:
               idx = target_domain.keys()[0]
               domain = target_domain.values()[0]
               if False in domain:
                   args.pop(idx)
       return super(ProductProduct, self).search(args=args,
                                             offset=offset,
                                             limit=limit,
                                             order=order,
                                             count=count)
   ```

What I try to do here is when they detected 'partner_channel_id' in context and domain like this ['sales_channel_ids', '=', False], I removed that domain and keep the rest (customer doesn't have channel can see all the products, no filtering products from them).

Comment: for sure it is a good solution, I'm just telling you mine is shorter and easier :) besides, I've used it in my own code!